# Are riding mowers required to have emissions controls in the US?

Tags: emissions, lawnmower

I know that regular push mowers are not required to have any sort of emissions controls, so mowing is pretty terrible environmentally. Riding mowers are bigger, and burn more gas, so without any sort of emissions controls I would assume they could be similarly terrible, except worse.

I'm considering getting a riding mower to replace my push mower that bit the bucket, but if it has no emissions controls, I'd second guess my decision. Can anyone chime in on what if any emissions standards riding mowers are held to?

Edit: Per agentp I'm located in the US, specifically Kansas.

Comment: you should specify where you are located, such regs can vary a lot.

Comment: regulations aside, look for one with fuel injection and a catalytic converter and you will be worlds better than your old carb push mower.

Comment: I'm not aware of any regulations on mowers in the US, but I don't know for sure. How about an electric mower?

Comment: @Spivonious That's my alternative, but the only electric mower I know of is a push mower. I would also reallly like to have a riding mower if they aren't super un-green

Comment: Interesting and related piece of news: http://www.nytimes.com/2006/04/24/us/24lawn.html

Comment: Yeah I would be very afraid of fires if my mower had a catalytic converter on it. Dry grass clippings + lots of heat + my garage = no more garage.

Comment: How about a push one and get exercise at the same time.. :) or one of the ecological ones that turn into food after 18 months or so - sheep !!

Comment: Your local government office will be able to tell you , just a phone call...